# Adding existing R packages to R environment in Anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, package, rstudio

I have two environments for R: one that I use for Rstudio in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R` and another in Anaconda for Jupyter Notebooks in `/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/r/bin/R`.

I want to transfer my existing packages from Rstudio packages to Anaconda3. How could I do it safely?